# Publish a Web Site project so that it creates a .dll and not .aspx.cs files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I have inherited an old web forms app.  I didn't get a project or a solution, just the source code.  In Visual Studio, I tried to make a web app from it, but could not get that to work. So I just made a website project instead.

In this folder to which I am publishing, I expected to only have the .aspx files with a .dll in the bin. But instead I got no .dll, and it created files for all of the .aspx.cs files.

I poked around in the properties ('Use fixed naming and single page assemblies', etc) but no luck.

What do I need to do?

(It's possible this is a duplicate, but I've been unable to find answers in any similar posts.)

Comment: As far as I know, website projects execute the .cs file code on request.  If you want .dll's you need it to be a Web Application.

Comment: Hi Casey, You might find this useful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the publish options, specify that you want to precompile during publishing. Then you can click "Configure" to reach the "Advanced Precompile Settings", where you may want to tweak other things, such as unchecking "Allow precompiled site to be updatable".